# Please update generated flair images to new design, supporting higher resolutions

Tags: feature-request, design, flair

An oft-overlooked feature SO has, is the ability to generate a flair *image* for your user profile.

You can find the page for them, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/

Here are some rendered examples:

[image: default]
[image: dark]
[image: hotdog (why?)]

Please note that these images are actually *generated png files*, and not just plain HTML.

This feature is quite old already, and as such, has gotten a bit outdated.

On modern screens, there's two significant issues with the generated images:

- They use an old UI design.
- They're *tiny*, which means most browsers will upscale the images, making them blurry.

  - (No support for retina scaling)

What I would like to request is:

- Update the flair design so it's in line with the site's current design.
- Add support for larger images (double / quadruple scale, for example).
- Add support for SVG output; This would make theming a lot easier, and they're infinitely scalable.

Comment: I've merged this with a much-older duplicate. Feel free to edit some of this explanation and context into that question.